# bbpress user-roles or capabilities per forum

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles, bbpress

I'm trying to setup a bbpress with extended user capabilities.

### The problem

My goal is that users need to have different capabilities in each forum, i.e:

- UserA **can't access** ForumW
- UserA can **only read** topics and replies in ForumX
- UserA can **create topics and write replies** in ForumY
- UserA can **moderate** ForumZ

### Plugins

These are the plugins I tried so far, but without success:

- Ultimate Member, official 1.7 and the new 2.0 version
  https://ultimatemember.com/
  They claim that they're working on a groups extension for UltimateMember v2, which somehow looks promising, but as of now there's no release date and I still don't know if this extension is going to solve my problem.
- itthinx Groups plugin
  http://docs.itthinx.com/document/groups/
  Allows me to assign multiple groups to users and forums, but there's still a catch.

### First attempt

Since itthinx Groups plugin allows me to assign multiple groups to UserA, which is great, it's still not solving my issue.

So, I tried something like this:

- ForumX has the following groups assigned: `ForumX_readers`, `ForumX_writers`, `ForumX_moderators`
- UserA has the following groups assigned: `ForumX_readers`, `ForumY_writers`, `ForumZ_moderators`

But the problem is, since UserA belongs to groups that have `publish_replies` and `moderate` capabilities, he has full access to ForumX.

So what I need is an intersection of the forum-groups and the user-groups - which in this example is `ForumX_readers`.

### The promising part, but...

I digged into the code of the plugin and found the line that handles the capabilities of the user based on his assigned groups and quickly tried to get the current forum groups, to implement the intersection.

Unfortunatelly I was not able to access the `global $post`, the `$_GLOBALS['post']` nor the `$_REQUEST[]` variables in this part of code. Neither directly nor with an `apply_filters()` function, that I implemented into the part of the code myself.

UPDATE:
I was able to get the ID with `get_posts()` and the slug of the current forum/topic.

### So, my question

Is there any solution to my first attempt, which I may have overseen?

If not, is there maybe any other plugin that can solve my problem that I'm not aware of?

Or is something like that even impossible in bbpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research and trial & error, I finally figured it out.

First step to do is to set up the capabilities, which in my case look something like this.

[image]

In the plugins directory, there is the file `core/class-groups-user.php`. The `init_cache()` function retrieves the assigned groups to the user, and sets the according capabilities.

To not mess around to much with the core-plugin, I applied a filter to the `$group_ids` variable which can be found in **line: 415**.

```
foreach( $user_groups as $user_group ) {
    $group_ids[] = Groups_Utility::id( $user_group->group_id );
}

// added this line
$group_ids = apply_filters('filter_user_group_ids', $group_ids);`
```

I then created a new plugin, which hooks into this filter.

```
add_filter('filter_user_group_ids', 'dnmc_filter_groups', 10, 1);

function dnmc_filter_groups($user_group_ids) {
    $forum_id = dnmc_get_forum_id();
    if(!$forum_id) return $user_group_ids;

    $forum_group_ids   = Groups_Post_Access::get_read_group_ids( $forum_id);
    $user_restricted_forum_group_ids = array_intersect($user_group_ids, $forum_group_ids);

    return $user_restricted_forum_group_ids;

}

function dnmc_get_forum_id() {
    $args_topic = array(
      'name'        => basename( untrailingslashit( rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') ) ),
      'post_type'   => 'topic',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'numberposts' => 1
    );

    if($topic = get_posts($args_topic)) {
        return $topic[0]->post_parent;
    }

    $args_forum = array(
      'name'        => basename( untrailingslashit( rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') ) ),
      'post_type'   => 'forum',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'numberposts' => 1
    );

    if($forum = get_posts($args_forum)) {
        return $forum[0]->ID;
    }

    return false;
}
```